# How to paste text with leading "0" in excel

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I have this code that pastes entire txt file contents to my active workbook but it loses leading "0" in cells:

```
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

If FileToOpen <> False Then
Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
OpenBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
OpenBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BOM").Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
OpenBook.Close False
End If
```

I tried to work around it by adding

```
OpenBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
```

But it doesn't do the trick.

So how do I paste the contents and not lose leading "0"?

Comment: Does `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` help?

Comment: No because like I explained in the post - I am pasting from TXT file that temporarily opens as excel workbook that it copies from to may main workbook. The main workbook is getting formatted correctly prior to pasting into it

Comment: How many columns does the text file in discussion have? Is the number of columns variable? All the columns of the text file have the problem of first zero digit missing?

Comment: It varies so I use .usedrange

Comment: It the text file a tab/comma delimited type?

Comment: Sorry, cant see in the post where you are formatting the destination range?  only `openbook`s  Perhaps show how you're formatting `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BOM")` ?

Comment: I am not sure I correctly understood the question. **Does the open text file have the first zero digit and this disappears only when try pasting the data**? Or is the text file wrongly open, from this point of view?

Comment: did you try `xlPasteAll` instead of `xlPasteValues`?

Comment: No but xlPasteAll messes things up even worse as the destination workbook has a specific formatting. I am just trying to paste the contents not messing up the destination sheet formatting

Comment: So, the open text file has its first 0 characters in its place?

Comment: Yes TXT file contents are perfect as well as it did paste perfectly when I used to ctrl+a and ctrl+c before running the pasting VBA. Now that I'm trying to get rid of that manual action... formatting messed up and I suspect that I have to format that workbook in which the initial TXT file opens before copying and pasting it

Comment: I am formatting the worksheet prior to running this module and I do it by:

    Cells.Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

The problem as I have pinpointed is that this temporary excel workbook already opens the TXT contents with lost leading "0" and I'm not sure I can format that temporary workbook prior to importing the contents of .TXT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It will use a different way of opening the text file. If the number of columns is not constant, the code will firstly count them and then build an array able to make the file opening as you need:

```
Sub openAsTextTextFormat()
 Dim FileToOpen As Variant, arrTXT, nrCol As Long, arr(), i As Long
 Dim OpenBook As Workbook

 FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")


 If FileToOpen <> False Then
    'Check the number of text file columns:
    arrTXT = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(FileToOpen, 1).ReadAll, vbLf)
    nrCol = UBound(Split(arrTXT(0), vbTab))
    '______________________________________
    ReDim arr(nrCol) 'redim the format array
    For i = 0 To nrCol
        arr(i) = Array(1, 2) 'fill the format array with variant for TEXT Format!
    Next

    Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=FileToOpen, origin:=932, startRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        other:=True, OtherChar:="|", FieldInfo:=arr()
    Set OpenBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Stop ' The code will stop here! Please, check if the text file has been open with the correct format.
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BOM").Range("C1")
      
    OpenBook.Close False
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nope, still the same result

Comment: @Eduards: It is strange... If you format all the range where the values to be pasted, it should work. I will try a harder formatting and adapt the code.

Comment: I still feel that there's something to do with the way text is opened in that initial temporary excel workbook

Comment: @Eduards: if you see the first zero in the file, even if in my case it is automatically formatted as General, what wrong to be there...? If you are you sure that the zero character is there where it must be... I was asking about that in order to suggest opening the file AsText, clearly stating the format type. But it is respecting the text format, it looks not necessary...

Comment: The temporary excel in which that TXT is initially opened already loses the leading ) so I guess I pinpointed the problem, and I guess I can't format that temporary excel sheet prior to importing the contents of TXT file

Comment: @Eduards: I was almost sure about it... But I asked you three time about it and you said that it is well formatted. I will try making a piece of code able to open the text file with all fields formatted as text.

Comment: Sorry I understood you were asking about the initial .TXT file and if the leading "0" are there? Silly me :)

Comment: @Eduards: Please, try the code I placed instead the existing one. It happened that I almost finalized it until you answer my question about how the open text file looks in terms of format. I finalized it now and please test it and send some feedback. The code will stop after opening the text file. Please, see how the file looks and then go back to VBE and press F5 to make the ordinary copying. If this copying part will not work as you need, it is a big field to try in order to solve the issue... I asked with bold characters...

Comment: YUP, Now the initial imported contents from TXT maintains leading "0" and after I press F5 it pastes the table correctly BUT it messes up the formatting of the destination workbook. I think you are on the right path

Comment: @Eduards: I only answered your question! I have no idea what  "messes up the formatting of the destination workbook" means... . You did not place at least a picture explaining what is bothering you when pasting. We here, try helping people solving the problems **they asked about**.  We cannot imagine what other problems exist in your application. Such thigs are solved here asking a different question. Now, do you consider that my above code answered your question, as it has been formulated, or  not?

Comment: Sorry but no, You however helped pinpoint the issue of TXT importing to temporary excel already with lost leading "0"

Comment: @Eduards: But what does **"How to paste text with leading “0” in excel"** means? Didn't you ask that? Doesn't the above code open the text file as it should and copy its content with leading "0"?  We spent about to hours to solve a wrong, not solvable question, and now do you say that what you asked and being answered is not enough? How could we here know how is formatted **your destination workbook**?

Comment: I explained multiple times that before I used to open TXT file and copy  all contents manually and ran the macros for pasting it. This code in the post is how I tried to automate that action. If my method was wrong in the core, I'm sorry, I wasn't aware of that at the time. But still this doesn't bring me the same result as I got when doing it manually as explained above. I don't believe it's unsolvable as your code DID open TXT file in temporary excel workbook with leading zeros. Thank you for helping me pinpoint the issue!

Answer (score 4):

To do what you want, you cannot **OPEN** the file.  You must **IMPORT** the file. That way you can designate the data as being text **before** Excel turns it into a numeric value.  *Once Excel turns it into a number, formatting alone will not recover the original textual value*

eg, to import the file, use the `Workbooks.OpenText` method:

```
Application.Workbooks.OpenText _
    Filename:=FileToOpen, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    comma:=True, Tab:=False, semicolon:=False, Space:=False, other:=False, _
    fieldinfo:=Array(Array(1, xlTextFormat), Array(2, xlTextFormat))
```

Then you can do a simple copy/paste operation and the text property should be maintained.

eg:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:= 'your fully qualified destination
```

Putting it all together, something like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub due()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Application.Workbooks.OpenText _
        Filename:=FileToOpen, _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        comma:=True, Tab:=False, semicolon:=False, Space:=False, other:=False, _
        fieldinfo:=Array(Array(1, xlTextFormat), Array(2, xlTextFormat))
        
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BOM").Range("C1")
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
End If
End Sub
```

Note that you will need an array argument in `FieldInfo` for each column you want to be parsed as other than `General`, and no arguments for non-existent columns.  See Microsoft VBA Help for the `Workbooks.OpenText` method for more information.

**Original CSV**

[image]

**Pasted Values**

[image]

Comment: Error saying: Sorry, we couldn't find . is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

Comment: @Eduards I'm guessing you replaced **all** of your code, and not just the relevant portion. *Including the part of your code where you selected a file*  What is the value of `FileName` at the time you see the error?

Comment: Which would be the relevant part?

Comment: @Eduards The part of your code that opens the text file.  When you ran the code, did you select a file to open?  As happens when you ran your own code?

Comment: @Eduards Please see my last edit where I tried to modify your original code.

Comment: Thanks but that code just pastes the whole table in C and D columns messing up the formatting in the destination workbook

Comment: My answer was directed to maintaining the leading zero's, which was your question. I merely copied the paste part from your own code (simplified a bit). If you are also having problems pasting only relevant data, then you should pose that as a separate question, with examples of your input, desired output, and how you have modified your simple paste operation to try to solve that part of your problem.

Comment: No, the question is about how to import TXT file data into workbook maintaining leading "0" essentially

Comment: @Eduards  Your code has two different parts -- importing the text file; copying that import from one workbook to another.  You asked about maintaining the leading zero's and I showed you how to do that.  The copy/paste operation is a separate operation and has no particular relevance so far as either importing the text file or maintaining the leading zero's.  But, if what I have posted is irrelevant to your problem,  suggest you adopt a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the format of the destination range.

```
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim rng As Range

    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        Set rng = OpenBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BOM")
            .Range("C1").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).NumberFormat = "@"
            rng.Copy
            .Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
        OpenBook.Close False
    End If
```

Comment: That made no difference, I believe it's something to do with the workbook in which that TXT is essentially opened and copied from perhaps? Because I do format workbook as "@" before pasting into it.

Comment: When you open the text file are the leading zeroes retained? Have you considered importing the text file instead of opening it directly as a workbook? That should give you far more control of how the data is handled.

Comment: Yes, in TXT all the leading 0 are there.
If it's possible... but I don't know how to directly paste from TXT

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how many digits are those numbers. This code, as example, makes all numbers to have 6 digits, so it adds leading zeros until len of string is 6.

Also, it will copy 1 column to another column.

```
Sub test()
Dim MiMatriz As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim ZZ As Long
ZZ = 1 'first row where data is going to be pasted

MiMatriz = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

For i = 1 To UBound(MiMatriz) Step 1
    MiMatriz(i, 1) = "'" & Format(MiMatriz(i, 1), "000000")
Next i

Range("C" & ZZ & ":C" & ZZ + UBound(MiMatriz) - 1) = MiMatriz

Erase MiMatriz

End Sub
```

As you can see in the image below, column A would be the original and column C, numbers with leading zeros.

[image]

You can adapt this code to fit your needs.

Comment: Leading "0" number may vary and before I used this VBA code to automatically paste the TXT file contents, it did work before when I pressed ctrl+a followed by ctrl+c in a txt file and then launched the VBA code that pastes it in. So I wanted to get rid of that whole thing and copy automatically